# Limit of $s_n = \int\limits_0^1 \frac{nx^{n-1}}{1+x} dx$ as $n \to \infty$

Tags: sequences-and-series, integration, limits

Let $s_n$ be a sequence defined as given below for $n \geq 1$. Then find out $\lim\limits_{n \to
\infty} s_n$. 
 \begin{align}
  s_n = \int\limits_0^1 \frac{nx^{n-1}}{1+x} dx
 \end{align}

I have written a solution of my own, but I would like to know it is completely correct, and also I would like if people post more alternative solutions.

Comment: Is the downvote because of self-answering?

Comment: Probably. Why did you post a question to which you already knew the answer?

Comment: A few reasons
1. It gives me oppurtunity to verify that the solution is indeed correct. (I self study, so even though I get an answer and I am pretty sure about it, there is no real way to verify the solution completely.)
2. It allows probably other people to offer me better solutions.
3. I can do so on a blog, but then it might not get the same attention on the blog.
4. MSE's editing capabilities are better than almost all other blogging software I have found.

Comment: That's not always seen as a good thing for Math.SE. See: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4680/is-answering-own-question-okay

Comment: @ToddWilcox Counterpoint. http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/2244/14082

Comment: I did not downvote, I was offering a possible reason why someone might have. Notice I wrote "not always seen...", by which I meant some people won't like you asking a question to which you already know the answer and therefore probably one of those people downvoted your question. I'm not advocating any position on the subject one way or the other.

Comment: Okay. No problems. :-)
Generally, when people downvote, and the OP asks the reason, it is expected that the person who downvoted leave a comment about it. And hence, my assumption.

Comment: Sadly I think there are many who downvote without comment, regardless of whether an explanation is requested or not.

Comment: I didn't downvote either, but it seems stylistically and logically wrong: the question is "is the following I reproduce in the question text correct?", the answer "yes/no" with reason. I jabs answered my own questions, when I didn't get answers or, after my thought, believed I could improve on other posting; answering your own questions isn't wrong per se. It's also simply more convenient to have the actual question on top.

Comment: It could also be seen as "reputation boosting": answer a question you can answer well, and get upvoted for the answer you knew in advance.

Comment: +1: I see no problem posting a question for which you already know the answer and asking for alternative approaches.

Comment: If you are looking for *alternate* approaches, you might post *your* approach so that we know how *not* to answer.

Comment: See also: [How to integrate this type of integral: $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}{\int_ 0^1}\frac{n x^{n-1}}{1+x}dx$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1501419)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a solution based on order statistics, similar to [my answer here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/181871/computing-lim-limits-n-to-inftyn-int-0-pi-2xfx-cos-n-xdx/181888#181888).

Let $X_1,\dots, X_n$ be i.i.d. uniform(0,1) random variables. 
The distribution function of $X$ is $F(x)=x$ and density $f(x)=1$ for $0\leq x\leq 1$.
Now let $M=\max(X_1,\dots, X_n)$; its density function is 
$$f_M(x)=n F(x)^{n-1}f_X(x)=n\,x^{n-1}\text{ for }0\leq x\leq 1.$$ 
Also, it is not hard to see that  $M\to 1$ in distribution as $n\to\infty$.
Now $$\int_0^1 {n x^{n-1}\over 1+x} \,dx =\int_0^1 {1\over 1+x}\, f_M(x) \,dx
=\mathbb{E}\left({1\over 1+M}\right).$$

This converges to 
${1\over 1+1}={1\over 2}$ as $n\to\infty$.

Comment: Thanks. A different solution. :-)

Comment: @MikeSpivey Yeah, it's the way I think. Some of the other answers here are great, too.

Comment: @Byron: If I may say so, I often enjoy your answers that use probability and statistics to answer questions that appear to be outside of those fields.  They are close enough to the way I think that I can appreciate them, but I often wouldn't think of those arguments myself.

Comment: @MikeSpivey Thanks for the kind words. I learn a lot from your answers, too.

Answer (score 16):

We simplify the formulate for $s_n$ by integrating by parts.

\begin{align}
   s_n &= \int\limits_0^1 \frac{nx^{n-1}}{1+x} d x \\
       &= \left[
          \frac{1}{1+x} \int nx^{n-1} d x  
          - \int \frac{1}{\left(1+x\right)^2} \left(\int nx^{n-1} d x\right) d x
          \right]^1_0 \\
       &= \left[\frac{1}{1+x} \int nx^{n-1} d x\right]^1_0 
          - \left[\int \frac{1}{\left(1+x\right)^2} \left(\int nx^{n-1} dx\right) d x\right]^1_0 \\
       &= \left[\frac{x^n}{1+x}\right]^1_0  
          - \left[\int \frac{x^n}{\left(1+x\right)^2} d x\right]^1_0 \\
       &= \frac{1}{2} - \int\limits_0^1 \frac{x^n}{\left(1+x\right)^2} d x \\ 
  \end{align}

Now we estimate the remaining integral in the expression 
  \begin{align}
   I(n) &= \int\limits_0^1 \frac{x^n}{\left(1+x \right)^2} d x \\
        &\leq \int\limits_0^1 x^n d x \\
        &= \frac{1}{n+1}
  \end{align}

Hence, $I(n) \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$.

And so, the expression can be rewritten as 
  \begin{align}
   \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} s_n = \frac{1}{2}
  \end{align}

Comment: What do you mean by $I(n) = e^{\log(x)n}$ in the last line?

Comment: Added the explanation. I hope its correct.

Comment: It is not; you can't just pull a $\log x$ out of the integral since you're integrating with respect to $x$.

Comment: Arrrrgh. Thanks.

Comment: $I(n)\leq \int_0^1 x^n dx={1\over n+1}.$

Answer (score 10):

We use [a basic result](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/168163/14082) in calculus, namely $\lim_{n\to \infty}n\int_0^1x^nf(x)  \ dx=f(1)$, $f$ continuous on $[0,1]$
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(\frac{n}{n-1}\times (n-1)\int\limits_0^1 x^{n-1} \frac{1}{(1+x)} dx\right)=\frac{1}{2}$$

Chris.

Comment: What is the name or proof of this basic result?

Comment: @Alex: I don't know if it has a name. Our teacher told us once that the result may be easily proved with the calculus knowledge in high school. This link will help you: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/168163/find-functions-family-satisfying-lim-n-to-infty-n-int-01-xn-fx-f1

Comment: Nice solution Chris'ssister! :-) Your question and the corresponding answers provide a decent tool. :-)

Comment: @OrangeHarvester: Thanks! :-) are you Jayesh? (sister here now)

Comment: Yes. I am Jayesh. Name changed for a month.

Answer (score 7):

Notice
 (1) $\frac{s_n}{n} + \frac{s_{n+1}}{n+1} = \int_0^1 x^{n-1} dx = \frac{1}{n} \implies s_n + s_{n+1} = 1 + \frac{s_{n+1}}{n+1}$.
 (2) $s_n = n\int_0^1 \frac{x^{n-1}}{1+x} dx < n\int_0^1 x^{n-1} dx = 1$
 (3) $s_{n+1} - s_n = \int_0^1 \frac{d (x^{n+1}-x^n)}{1+x} = \int_0^1 x^n \frac{1-x}{(1+x)^2} dx > 0$

(2+3) $\implies s = \lim_{n\to\infty} s_n$ exists and (1+2) $\implies s+s = 1 + 0 \implies s = \frac{1}{2}$.

In any event, $s_n$ can be evaluated exactly to $n (\psi(n) - \psi(\frac{n}{2}) - \ln{2})$ where $\psi(x)$ is the diagamma function. Since $\psi(x) \approx \ln(x) - \frac{1}{2x} - \frac{1}{12x^2} + \frac{1}{120x^4} + ... $ as $x \to \infty$, we know:
$$s_n \approx \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{4 n} - \frac{1}{8 n^3} + ...$$

Answer (score 7):

Using the substitution $x\mapsto x^{1/n}$ and Dominated Convergence,
$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^1\frac{nx^{n-1}}{1+x}\,\mathrm{d}x
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^1\frac1{1+x^{1/n}}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\int_0^1\frac12\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\frac12
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Nice Robjohn . I have a doubt . When $\displaystyle \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} $ and $0<x<1.$. Then $(x)^n=0.$ So $\displaystyle \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\int^{1}_{0}\frac{n x^{n-1}}{1+x}dx=0$. please explain me where i am wrong. Thanks

Comment: @DurgeshTiwari: You cannot simply exchange limits and integrals. There are rules for doing so. Above, I used Dominated Convergence, which says that if $|f_n(x)|\le g(x)$ for all $n$ and $x\in[0,1]$ and $\int_0^1g(x)\,\mathrm{d}x\lt\infty$, then $$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\int_0^1f_n(x)\,\mathrm{d}x=\int_0^1\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}f_n(x)\,\mathrm{d}x$$ There is no such $g(x)$ that dominates $\frac{nx^{n-1}}{1+x}$ for all $n$.