# Evaluate the limit of the integral of the sequence of function

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $$s_n=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{nx^{n-1}}{(1+x)}\,dx$$ for $n\geq 1$.
Then where sequence $(s_n)$ converges.
There are four options (A)$0$ (B)$\frac1{2}$ (C)$1$ (D)$\infty$

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik I have done $\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^{n-1}}{1+x}\,dx=\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+1}+\frac{1}{n+2}-... $. Then I cannot do anything.

Comment: Do you understand the hint given below?

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik Yes i think limit is 1/2. sorry for previous one

Comment: yes... that is it!

Comment: Hmm, I keep getting $s_n=n \cdot \sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k}$ which diverges. Where did I make a mistake?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Limit of $s_n = \int\limits_0^1 \frac{nx^{n-1}}{1+x} dx$ as $n \to \infty$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/292251/limit-of-s-n-int-limits-01-fracnxn-11x-dx-as-n-to-infty)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HINT:

$$\frac{s_n}n+\frac{s_{n-1}}{n-1}=?$$

Comment: I do not understand how does that help...$$\frac{s_n}n+\frac{s_{n-1}}{n-1}=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^{n-1}}{(1+x)}\,dx+ \int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^{n-2}}{(1+x)}\,dx=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^{n-1}+x^{n-2}}{(1+x)} \,dx$$ but then.. :O

Comment: Then factor $x$, cancel and integrate

Comment: @mathemagician : Oh yeah!!... $$\frac{s_n}n+\frac{s_{n-1}}{n-1}=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^{n-1}}{(1+x)}\,dx+ \int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^{n-2}}{(1+x)}\,dx=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^{n-1}+x^{n-2}}{(1+x)} \,dx=\int_{0}^{1}x^{n-2}\,dx= :) :)$$ Done...

Comment: @lab bhattacharjee :Is the limit equal to 1/2

Comment: @rajkamalmath, We have $$s_n+\frac{s_{n-1}}{\frac1{1-\frac1n}}=\frac1{\frac1{1-\frac1n}}$$

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}s_n+\frac{\lim_{n\to\infty}s_{n-1}}{\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1{1-\frac1n}}=\frac1{\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1{1-\frac1n}}$$

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}s_n+\lim_{n\to\infty}s_{n-1}=1$$  If $$\lim_{n\to\infty}s_n=S,\lim_{n\to\infty}s_{n-1}=? $$

Comment: @labbhattacharjee : so S=$\frac{1}{2}$, for that reason I have told limit is $\frac1{2}$. Thanks!