# Limit of sequence $ S_n $=$\int_0^1 \frac{nx^{n-1}}{1+x}dx $

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $ S_n $=$\int_0^1 \frac{nx^{n-1}}{1+x}dx $ for n$ \ge $1 then as n tends to infinity sequence tends to:

1.0
2.1
3. 1/2
4. Infinity

Is there any other way, than to first do integration, and then take limit?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/292251/limit-of-s-n-int-limits-01-fracnxn-11x-dx-as-n-to-infty?rq=1

Comment: $$\require{cancel}
S_n = \int_0^1 \frac{nx^{n-1}}{1+x}dx
= \int_0^1 \frac{1}{1+x} dx^n = 
\color{red}{\cancelto{\frac12}{\color{gray}{\left[\frac{x^n}{1+x}\right]_0^1}}} 
+ 
\color{red}{\cancelto{0}{\color{gray}{\int_0^1 \frac{x^n}{(1+x)^2} dx}}}
$$

Comment: @achillehui: fantastic formatting, how do you get that?

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio It uses the [cancel](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/tex.html#cancel) extension of MathJAX. see this [answer](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/13183) for some sample usages.

Answer (score 1):

As stated by achille hui in his pretty comment, integration by parts leads to:
$$ S_n = \color{red}{\frac{1}{2}}+\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^n}{(1+x)^2}\,dx $$
but obviously:
$$ 0\leq \int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^n}{(1+x)^2}\,dx \leq \int_{0}^{1} x^n\,dx = \frac{1}{n+1}$$
so the limit is just $\displaystyle\color{red}{\frac{1}{2}}.$

Comment: how did you come up with inequalities in last step expecially right one , what is idea for writing ?

Comment: @tomb_raider: the only idea is that over $[0,1]$ we have $\frac{1}{(1+x)^2}\leq 1$, hence we can bound $S_n-\frac{1}{2}$ with a well-known integral converging to zero.

Comment: yes, thank you .