# Interesting integral: $\int_0^1{\frac{nx^{n-1}}{x+1}}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Find the value of $$\int_0^1{\frac{nx^{n-1}}{x+1}}dx.$$

I had no luck while integrating it. I also tried differentiating w.r.t n but still couldn't reach anywhere. Need help.

Comment: For what it's worth, Mathematica returns a result in terms of the [digamma function.](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DigammaFunction.html)  This suggests to me that it may not have a "nice" closed form.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert It has closed forms for $n\in\mathbb N$.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt There seems to be a different closed form in elementary functions for each positive integer $n,$ but not a single closed form in elementary functions that is good for every positive integer $n.$

Comment: @DavidK How is Chapper's answer not closed form?

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt As soon as you see $\sum_{k=1}^n,$ it's not a closed form.

Comment: @DavidK As far as I care, finite summations involving elementary functions are closed form solutions of integrals.  But of course, that is up to debate.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt If the summation is $\sum_{k=1}^{1017}$ or some other sum with a fixed number of terms, then yes. But there's a whole class of problems along the lines of how to express $\sum_{k=1}^n k^3$ (for example) in closed, form, or how to write the $n$th term of a recursively defined sequence in closed form.

Comment: @DavidK Well I think depending on context, finite sums with variable indexes could easily be considered closed form.

Comment: After trying to [search using Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Cint_0%5E1%7B%5Cfrac%7Bnx%5E%7Bn-1%7D%7D%7Bx%2B1%7D%7Ddx%24&p=1) if find a few posts about limit for $n\to\infty$, but not about actual value of the integral. Like [Limit of $s_n = \int\limits_0^1 \frac{nx^{n-1}}{1+x} dx$ as $n \to \infty$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/292251) and other questions [linked there](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/292251).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Put $y=1+x$ and the integral becomes
$$ \int_{1}^2 \frac{n(y-1)^{n-1}}{y} \, dy = \int_1^2 \sum_{k=0}^n n\binom{n-1}{k} (-1)^{n-k-1} y^{k-1} \, dy = \left[ n(-1)^{n-1}\log{y} + \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{n}{k} \binom{n-1}{k} (-1)^{n-k-1} y^k \right]_1^2 \\
= n(-1)^{n-1}\log{2} + \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{n}{k} \binom{n-1}{k} (-1)^{n-k-1}(2^k-1). $$

Answer (score 11):

HINT:

If $\displaystyle I_n=\int_0^1\dfrac{nx^{n-1}}{x+1}dx,$

$$I_{m+1}+I_m=\int_0^1\dfrac{(m+1)x^m+mx^{m-1}}{x+1}dx$$ 
$$=m\int_0^1x^{m-1}\ dx+\int_0^1\dfrac{x^m}{1+x}dx=1+\int_0^1\dfrac{x^m}{1+x}dx$$

Again if $\displaystyle J_m=\int_0^1\dfrac{x^m}{1+x}dx,$

$$J_{m+1}+J_m=?$$

Comment: Could we just say for $n \neq 0,$ $I_n = \frac1n J_{n-1},$ and skip directly to the $J_{m+1}+J_m$ part?

Comment: @DavidK, Not sure if I've understood u. Please elaborate.

Comment: Oops, that should be $I_n = nJ_{n-1},$ not $\frac1n J_{n-1}.$

Answer (score 5):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[8px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{1}{n\,x^{n - 1} \over x + 1}\,\dd x & =
n\int_{0}^{1}{x^{n - 1} - x^{n} \over 1 - x^{2}}\,\dd x
\,\,\,\stackrel{x^{2}\ \mapsto\ x}{=}\,\,\,
{1 \over 2}\,n\int_{0}^{1}{x^{n/2 - 1} - x^{n/2 - 1/2} \over 1 - x}\,\dd x
\\[5mm] & =
{1 \over 2}\,n\bracks{%
\int_{0}^{1}{1 - x^{n/2 - 1/2} \over 1 - x}\,\dd x -
\int_{0}^{1}{1 - x^{n/2 - 1} \over 1 - x}\,\dd x}
\\[5mm] & =
\bbx{{1 \over 2}\,n\pars{H_{n/2 - 1/2} - H_{n/2 - 1}}}
\end{align}

> where $\ds{H_{z}}$ is the [Harmonic Number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number#Harmonic_numbers_for_real_and_complex_values).

Answer (score 1):

We can write the integral as
$$
F(n) = \int_0^{\;1} {\frac{{nx^{n - 1} }}{{1 + x}}dx}  = \int_0^{\;1} {\frac{1}{{1 + x}}dx^n }  = \int_0^{\;1} {\left( {1 - \frac{x}{{1 + x}}} \right)dx^n }  = 1 - \int_0^{\;1} {\frac{x}{{1 + x}}dx^n } 
$$

$F(n+1)$ will be
$$
F(n + 1) = \int_0^{\;1} {\frac{{\left( {n + 1} \right)x^n }}{{1 + x}}dx}  = \int_0^{\;1} {\frac{x}{{1 + x}}dx^n }  + \int_0^1 {\frac{{x^n }}{{1 + x}}dx}  = 1 - F(n) + \frac{1}{{n + 1}}F(n + 1)
$$
i.e.:
$$
\begin{array}{l}
 \left( {1 - \frac{1}{{n + 1}}} \right)F(n + 1) = 1 - F(n) \\ 
 \frac{{F(n + 1)}}{{n + 1}} = \frac{1}{n} - \frac{{F(n)}}{n} \\ 
 \left( { - 1} \right)^{\,n} \frac{{F(n + 1)}}{{n + 1}} = \frac{{\left( { - 1} \right)^{\,n} }}{n} + \left( { - 1} \right)^{\,n - 1} \frac{{F(n)}}{n} \\ 
 \end{array}
$$

So we have
$$
\left\{ \begin{array}{l}
 G(n) = \left( { - 1} \right)^{\,n} \frac{{F(n + 1)}}{{n + 1}} \\ 
 G(0) = F(1) = \ln 2 \\ 
 G(n + 1) - G(n) = \frac{{\left( { - 1} \right)^{\,n + 1} }}{{n + 1}} \\ 
 \end{array} \right.
$$

which leads to
$$ \bbox[lightyellow] {  
\begin{array}{l}
 G(n) = \ln (2) + \sum\limits_{k = 0}^{n - 1} {\frac{{\left( { - 1} \right)^{\,k + 1} }}{{k + 1}}}  = \left( { - 1} \right)^{\,n} \Phi \left( { - 1,1,n + 1} \right) \\ 
 F(n) = n\;\Phi \left( { - 1,1,n} \right) \\ 
 \end{array}
}$$
where $\Phi$ denotes the Lerch Transcendent.

In fact, by the integral representation of $\Phi$
$$
\Phi \left( {z,s,a} \right)\mathop  \equiv \limits^{def} \frac{1}
{{\Gamma (s)}}\int_0^\infty  {\frac{{t^{\,s - 1} e^{\, - a\,t} }}
{{1 - z\,e^{\, - \,t} }}dt} 
$$
and
$$
\Phi \left( { - 1,1,n} \right) = \int_{t\, = \,0}^\infty  {\frac{{e^{\, - n\,t} }}
{{1 + \,e^{\, - \,t} }}dt} \quad \xrightarrow{{e^{\, - \,t}  = x}}\quad  - \int_{x = 1}^0 {\frac{{x^{\,n - 1} }}
{{1 + \,x}}dt} 
$$