# Finding limit of I(n)..

Tags: calculus, integration, sequences-and-series, limits

Given: $$\ I(n) = \int_{0}^1 \frac {nx^{n-1}}{1+x}dx$$
Find $\lim_{n \to\infty} I(n)$.

Please help me with this. I cannot find any way to do this.

Comment: Please include your work, up till which point you could go, and where you got stuck.

Comment: i cannot think of any way to this ..

Comment: i used sandwich but am not sure of whether its right to do or not and by that way I am getting zero as answer

Comment: What is $nx^{n-1}$? Have you seen this before?

Comment: $I(n)$ is a definite integral and $x$ is a dummy variable. You don't need $0<x<1$

Comment: its given in the question

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/292251/limit-of-s-n-int-limits-01-fracnxn-11x-dx-as-n-to-infty

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Hint**
Use integration by parts. Indeed,
$$
\int_{0}^1\frac{nx^{n-1}}{1+x}\,dx=\left[\frac{x^n}{1+x}\right]_{0}^1+\int_{0}^1\frac{x^n}{(1+x)^2}\,dx
$$
Let $n\to\infty$ and apply the dominated convergence theorem to the second integral on the RHS.

Comment: can you elaborate it .. I dont know dominated convergence theorem

Comment: @SatyamKumar this is why it is so important to include context and your efforts. Without it, you will get answers, (that users work hard to write!) which do not help you

Comment: @satyamkumar One doesn't need to apply the DCT.  The remaining integral, call it $f_n$,.satisfies the inequalities $\frac1{4(n+1)}\le f_n\le \frac1{n+1}$.  Do you understand why that is true?

Comment: Yeah , i get it why f(n) lies in that interval .

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
$\ds{\Large\left. a\right)}$

> With
>   [Laplace's Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace%27s_method):

\begin{align}
\lim_{n \to \infty}\int_{0}^{1}{nx^{n - 1} \over 1 + x}\,\dd x & =
\lim_{n \to \infty}\bracks{n\int_{0}^{1}{\pars{1 - x}^{n - 1} \over 2 - x}
\,\dd x} =
\lim_{n \to \infty}\bracks{n\int_{0}^{1}
{\exp\pars{\bracks{n - 1}\ln\pars{1 - x}} \over 2 - x}\,\dd x}
\\[5mm] & =
\lim_{n \to \infty}\bracks{n\int_{0}^{\infty}
{\exp\pars{-\bracks{n - 1}x} \over 2 - 0}\,\dd x} =
{1 \over 2}\lim_{n \to \infty}\pars{n\,{1 \over n - 1}} = \bbx{1 \over 2}
\end{align}

---

$\ds{\Large\left. b\right)}$
\begin{align}
\lim_{n \to \infty}\int_{0}^{1}{nx^{n - 1} \over 1 + x}\,\dd x & =
\lim_{n \to \infty}\bracks{n\int_{0}^{1}{x^{n - 1} - x^{n} \over 1 - x^{2}}
\,\dd x} =
\lim_{n \to \infty}\bracks{n\int_{0}^{1}{x^{n/2 - 1} - x^{n/2 - 1/2} \over
1 - x}\,{1 \over 2}\dd x}
\\[5mm] & =
{1 \over 2}\lim_{n \to \infty}\bracks{n\pars{%
\int_{0}^{1}{1 - x^{n/2 - 1/2} \over 1 - x}\,\dd x -
\int_{0}^{1}{1 - x^{n/2 - 1} \over 1 - x}\,\dd x}}
\\[5mm] & =
{1 \over 2}\lim_{n \to \infty}\bracks{n\pars{H_{n/2 - 1/2} - H_{n/2 - 1}}}
\qquad\pars{~H_{z}:\ Harmonic\ Number~}
\\[5mm] & = \bbx{1 \over 2}
\end{align}

> Note that
>   $\ds{H_{z} \sim \ln\pars{z} + \gamma + {1 \over 2z} - {1 \over 12z^{2}}}$ as
>   $\ds{\verts{z} \to \infty.\quad}$ $\ds{\gamma}$ is the
>   *Euler-Mascheroni Constant*.