# $\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty}\left[(n+1) \int_{0}^{1} x^{n} \ln (1+x) d x\right]$

Tags: calculus, limits, definite-integrals

$\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty}\left[(n+1) \int_{0}^{1} x^{n} \ln (1+x) d x\right]$

My work
$$
\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_{0}^{1} x^{n} \ln (1+x) d x
$$
can be simplified to:
$$
\begin{array}{c}
\ln (2)-\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_{0}^{1} \frac{x^{n+1}}{1+x} d x \\
\because\left|\int_{0}^{1} \frac{x^{n+1}}{1+x} d x\right| \leq \int_{0}^{1}\left|x^{n+1}\right| d x
\end{array}
$$
Now, here the bound $1+x$ is always greater than equal to 1
$$
\Rightarrow \frac{1}{1+x} \leq 1
$$
$$
\therefore \lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_{0}^{1} x^{n} \ln (1+x) d x=\ln (2)
$$

**Any shorter approach would be highly appreciated!**

*NB* although I have tried to solve this using Dominated Convergence theorem,but couldn't make it

Comment: This is the exact same as the question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/259079/find-the-value-of-lim-n-to-inftyn1-int-01xn-ln1xdx.

Answer (score 0):

Clearly
$$
I_n := (n+1) \int_0^1 x^n\, \log(1+x)\, dx \leq \log(2) \int_0^1(n+1)x^n\,dx = \log(2).
$$
On the other hand, for every $\epsilon\in (0,1)$ we have that
$$
\begin{align}
I_n & \geq (n+1) \int_{1-\epsilon}^1 x^n\, \log(1+x)\, dx
\\ & \geq \log(2-\epsilon) \int_{1-\epsilon}^1 (n+1) x^n\, dx = 
\log(2-\epsilon) \left[1 - (1-\epsilon)^{n+1} \right].
\end{align}
$$
Since the r.h.s. tends to $\log(2-\epsilon)$ as $n\to +\infty$, we conclude that
$\lim_n I_n = \log(2)$.