# Evaluate the limit of $(n+1)\int_0^1x^n\ln(1+x)\,dx$ when $n\to\infty$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, definite-integrals

> Evaluate the following limit : $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\left[(n+1)\int_0^1x^n\ln(1+x)\,dx\right].$$

We have , $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\left[(n+1)\int_0^1x^n\ln(1+x)\,dx\right]$$
$$=\lim_{n\to \infty}\int_0^1\ln(1+x)\,d(x^{n+1})$$Now put , $x^{n+1}=y$. Then , $$=\lim_{n\to \infty}\int_0^1\ln\left(1+y^{\frac{1}{n+1}}\right)\,dy$$Let , $\displaystyle g_n(y)=\ln\left(1+y^{\frac{1}{n+1}}\right)$.

> ## Edit  :
>
> Then , $\displaystyle g(y)=\lim_ng_n(y)=\ln 2$ in $(0,1]$.
>
> Now , $\displaystyle \sup_{x\in (0,1]}|g_n(y)-g(y)|=\sup_{x\in (0,1]}\ln\left(\frac{1+y^{\frac{1}{n+1}}}{2}\right)=0$. ( As , $y^{\frac{1}{n+1}}$ is monotone increasing function in $(0,1]$ , so $\ln\left(\frac{1+y^{\frac{1}{n+1}}}{2}\right)$ is also monotone increasing in $(0,1]$ and so it attains its maximum value at $y=1$ . ) **So , $\{g_n(y)\}$ converges uniformly to $\ln 2$.**

Then ,we can show that $g_n(y)$ converges uniformly to $\ln 2$ in $(0,1]$ and hence the given limit is $\ln 2$.

> Is this correct ? Does there any other technique to evaluate the limit ?

Comment: "Then ,we can show that $g_n(y)$ converges uniformly to $\ln 2$" Can we?

Comment: @ Did ) I can do it...So I don't think that it is necessary to enhance the length of the post including that analysis.

Comment: You can do it? I see... But wait, it seems that $g_n(0)=0$ after all. This is strange, don't you think?

Comment: "Then ,we can show that $g_n(y)$ converges uniformly to $\ln 2$ in $(0,1]$" Hmmm... how to say these things? Well, you know, the modified version, "cleverly" replacing $[0,1]$ by $(0,1]$, is **as deadly wrong as the previous one**. There is no uniform convergence here, so you better start right away finding some other argument.

Comment: @Did) See my **Edit** in question and tell me what's my mistake to show uniform convergence ....

Comment: Plotting the graphs of some functions $g_n$ could help... $$\sup_{x\in (0,1]}|g_n(y)-g(y)|=\sup_{x\in (0,1]}\left|\ln\left(\frac{1+y^{\frac{1}{n+1}}}{2}\right)\right|=\left|\ln\left(\frac{1+0^{\frac{1}{n+1}}}{2}\right)\right|=\ln2\ne0$$

Comment: By the way, I copied the beginning of the formula in my comment from your post and there is a typo: the second supremum should read over $y\in(0,1]$, not over $x\in(0,1]$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you don't actually have uniform convergence, as you claim.  In particular, $x^{1/n}$ does not converge to $1$ uniformly on $(0,1]$.  However, you have monotone convergence, which is sufficient by the monotone convergence theorem.

Another way to evaluate the limit: with integration by parts, we have
$$
\int_0^1(n+1)x^n \ln(x+1)\,dx = 
(1)^{n+1}\ln(2) - \int_0^1 \frac{x^{n+1}}{x+1}dx
$$
And, we have
$$
0 \leq \int_0^1 \frac{x^{n+1}}{x+1}dx \leq \int_0^1 \frac{x^{n+1}}{1}dx = \frac{1}{n+2}
$$

Comment: "Your method looks fine." Hmmm... See comments on main.

Comment: @Did looks like you're right. Fixed.

Comment: @@Omnomnomnom) See my Edit in question and tell me what's my mistake to show uniform convergence .... I deal with the function $\displaystyle \ln\left(1+y^{\frac{1}{n+1}}\right)$  about uniform convergence , **NOT** only the function $x^{1/n}$ which is NOT uniform convergent , as you say in your answer.

Comment: @@ Omnomnomnom ) Please response...where my mistake ?

Comment: Note that $\ln(1+x)\approx x$ for $x\in (-1,1)$. In any case, Did has the right idea.

Answer (score 2):

Let $U_1,U_2,\dots$ be i.i.d. uniform (0,1) random variables and set 
$M_n=\max(U_1,\dots, U_{n})$. Then $M_{n+1}$ has density $(n+1) x^n$ for $x\in(0,1)$. As $n\to\infty$ we have  $M_{n+1}\to 1$ in distribution, so 
$$\int_0^1 (n+1) x^n \ln(1+x)\,dx=\mathbb{E}(\ln(1+M_{n+1}))\to \ln(1+1)=\ln(2).$$

---

Similar solutions using order statistics:

[Limit of $s_n = \int\limits_0^1 \frac{nx^{n-1}}{1+x} dx$ as $n \to \infty$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/292251/limit-of-s-n-int-limits-01-fracnxn-11x-dx-as-n-to-infty/292273#292273)

[Computing $\lim\limits_{n\to+\infty}n\int_{0}^{\pi/2}xf(x)\cos ^n xdx$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/181871/computing-lim-limits-n-to-inftyn-int-0-pi-2xfx-cos-n-xdx/181888#181888)

[Solving $\lim_{n\to\infty}(n\int_0^{\pi/4}(\tan x)^ndx)$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1391863/solving-lim-n-to-inftyn-int-0-pi-4-tan-xndx/1391904#1391904)

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
&\bbox[10px,#ffd]{\lim_{n\to \infty}
\bracks{\pars{n + 1}\int_{0}^{1}x^{n}\ln\pars{1 + x}\,\dd x}} =
\lim_{n\to \infty}
\bracks{\pars{n + 1}\int_{0}^{1}\pars{1 - x}^{n}\ln\pars{2 - x}\,\dd x}
\\[5mm] = &\
\lim_{n\to \infty}
\bracks{\pars{n + 1}\int_{0}^{1}\exp\pars{n\ln\pars{1 - x}}
\ln\pars{2 - x}\,\dd x}
\\[5mm] = &\
\lim_{n\to \infty}
\bracks{\pars{n + 1}\int_{0}^{\infty}\exp\pars{-nx}\ln\pars{2}\,\dd x}
\qquad\pars{~Laplace'\!s\ Method~}
\\[5mm] = &\
\ln\pars{2}\lim_{n \to \infty}\bracks{\pars{n + 1}{1 \over n}} =
\bbx{\ln\pars{2}}
\end{align}

> See [Laplace's Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace%27s_method).

Comment: What is Laplace Method ? Can you please give some detail about it ?

Comment: @Empty [Laplace's Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace%27s_method).