# How to find limit $\lim_{n\to \infty}\left[(n+1)\int_{0}^{1}x^n\ln(x+1)dx\right]$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

How to find this limit;

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\left[(n+1)\int_{0}^{1}x^n\ln(x+1)dx\right]$$

What techniques can I use here? Thanks for reading and help.

This question was asked in [GATE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graduate_Aptitude_Test_in_Engineering) 2008.

Comment: Maybe write $\ln(x+1)$ as a power series?

Comment: @D_S Thanks for the help. I will try it out.

Comment: Please give more [context](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9960). Providing context not only assures that this is not simply copied from a homework assignment, but also allows answers to be better directed at where the problem lies and to be within the proper scope. Please [avoid "I have no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/27933). Defining keywords and trying a simpler, similar problem often helps.

Comment: This was asked in PhD entrance examination GATE 2008, @robjohn

Comment: The idea is to put that information into the question. Often, questions lacking context are closed because of that.

Comment: @robjohn I will edit the question. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: It seems that question about this limit has been asked before: [Evaluate the limit of $(n+1)\int_0^1x^n\ln(1+x)\,dx$ when $n\to\infty$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1500671). I found the linked question [using Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Clim_%7Bn%5Cto%20%5Cinfty%7D%5Cleft%5B(n%2B1)%5Cint_%7B0%7D%5E%7B1%7Dx%5En%5Cln(x%2B1)dx%5Cright%5D%24&p=1). More tips on searching: [How to search on this site?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/29265)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:**

You can use IBP to evaluate the integral as: $$\bigg[\frac{x^{n+1}\ln(x+1)}{n+1}\bigg]^1_0-\frac{1}{n+1}\int_0^1{\frac{x^{n+1}}{x+1}dx}$$

$$=\frac{1}{n+1}\bigg(\ln 2 -\int_0^1{\frac{x^{n+1}}{x+1}dx}\bigg)$$

This means you are looking for $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\bigg(\ln(2)-\int_0^1{\frac{x^{n+1}}{x+1}dx}\bigg)$$

Can you prove this integral goes to $0$?

Comment: Sorry I spent some time but can't see why this integral goes to zero. Can you give some hint?

Comment: Remember that integrals calculate the area under the curve. If $f(x)=\frac{x^{n+1}}{x+1}$, can you see that $f(0)=0, f(1)=\frac12$ and $f(x)$ is increasing? Then you just need to show the values between these two get smaller as you increase $n$. This follows from $x^m<x^n$ for $x\in(0,1)$ if $m>n$

Comment: or Dominated Convergence since $\frac{x^{n+1}}{x+1}\le1$ or comparison with the integral of $x^{n+1}\le\frac{x^{n+1}}{x+1}$.

Answer (score 2):

*Too long for a comment but added for your curiosity (even if too complex).*

You have received good answers already so I shall focus on the asymptotics of
$$I_n=(n+1)\int_{0}^{1}x^n\ln(x+1)\,dx$$

First of all, if you know about the Gaussian hypergeometric function, there is an antiderivative
$$\int x^n\ln(x+1)\,dx=\frac{x^{n+1} (\, _2F_1(1,n+1;n+2;-x)+(n+1) \log (x+1)-1)}{(n+1)^2}$$ and, assuming $n>0$, using the bounds
$$\int_0^1 x^n\ln(x+1)\,dx=\frac{(n+1)\left( H_{\frac{n}{2}}- H_{\frac{n-1}{2}}\right)+n \log (4)+2\log (2)-2}{2
   (n+1)^2}$$ Using the asymptotics of harmonic numbers
$$H_p=\gamma +\log(p) +\frac{1}{2 p}-\frac{1}{12
   p^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{p^4}\right)$$ and continuing with Taylor series, we should end with
$$I_n=\log (2)-\frac{1}{2 n}+\frac{3}{4
   n^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right)$$

For sure, the same result would be obtained using Rhys Hughes's answer since 
$$\int \frac{x^{n+1}}{x+1}\,dx=-\frac{x^{n+1} (\, _2F_1(1,n+1;n+2;-x)-1)}{n+1}$$
$$\int_0^1 \frac{x^{n+1}}{x+1}\,dx=\frac{1}{2} \left(H_{\frac{n+1}{2}}-H_{\frac{n}{2}}\right)$$

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will spend some time understanding it.:)