# Limit of integral $\lim_{n \to \infty} n\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \tan^n x\,dx$

Tags: limits, definite-integrals

Compute

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}n \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\tan^n x\,dx$$

I tried to define a recurrence with $I_n=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \tan^n x$ :

$I_0 = \frac{\pi}{4}, I_1=\ln\sqrt{2}$

and $I_{n}=\frac{1}{n-1}-I_{n-2}$, but I can't complete it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Solving $\lim_{n\to\infty}(n\int_0^{\pi/4}(\tan x)^ndx)$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1391863/solving-lim-n-to-inftyn-int-0-pi-4-tan-xndx) – found with [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Clim_%7Bn%20%5Cto%20%5Cinfty%7Dn%20%5Cint_0%5E%7B%5Cfrac%7B%5Cpi%7D%7B4%7D%7D%5Ctan%5En%20x%5C%2Cdx%24&p=2)

Answer (score 2):

Define $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}, f(x)=\dfrac{1}{1+x^2}$. Now, integrating by parts:

$$
\begin{aligned}
\int_0^1 (n+1)x^nf(x)\,dx &= \left[x^{n+1}f(x)\right]_0^1-\int_0^1x^{n+1}f'(x)\,dx \\
&= f(1)+2\int_0^1 \frac{x^{n+2}}{(1+x^2)^2}dx
\end{aligned}
$$

Using $1\leq 1+x^2\leq 2$ over $[0,1]$ we get

$$\frac{1}{2(n+3)}=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^1 x^{n+2}dx\leq 2\int_0^1\frac{x^{n+2}}{(1+x^2)^2}dx \leq 2\int_0^{1} x^{n+2}dx=\frac{2}{n+3}$$

and squeezing, we can easily see that:

$$2\int_0^1\frac{x^{n+2}}{(1+x^2)^2}dx \to 0$$

and therefore:

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}n\int_0^1 x^nf(x)\,dx=\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{n}{n+1}\int_0^1 (n+1)x^nf(x)\,dx=f(1)=\frac{1}{2}$$

Now substitute $x \to \tan x$ to get that the limit equals $\dfrac{1}{2}$.